# Table Header not Visible

Tags: magento-2.1, admin-panel

I have upload a 2.0.1 site to our production server and all is good apart from a number of the Admin Pages.

ie .

> Sales > Orders are missing the Table headers styling.

Can anyone suggest a solution as to why this is happening and a fix please.

[Correct Local Copy](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_znp6G9TvHWYnB5VHlqaVc5WmM)

[Remote copy missing the Table Headers](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_znp6G9TvHWdFg1WlZGeFRKVTA)

Comment: Removed your `pub/static and  var/generation , var/cache , var/pagecahe `directories. then run `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy` command and lastly run `cache :clean` command it will works

Answer (score 4):

Try to do following :

1. Removed your **pub/static** and **var/generation**,**var/cache**,**var/pagecahe**
   directories.
2. then run **setup:di:compile** and s**etup:static-content:deploy** command
3. lastly run **cache :clean** command it will works

Comment: I tried that and the same issue what i an noticing on the local copy is that the knockout template is wrapping the  span tag for each of the data-grid-cell-content cells.
**Locally:**
</th><!-- /ko --><!-- ko template: getHeader() -->
<th class="data-grid-th _sortable _draggable _ascend" data-bind="css: {
        _descend: sorting === 'desc'}, click: sort">
    <span class="data-grid-cell-content" data-bind="text: label">ID</span>
</th>
**Production:**
<!-- /ko --><!-- ko template: getHeader() -->
    <span class="data-grid-cell-content" data-bind="text: label">Purchase Point</span>

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem seen to be with Google Page cache when it is enabled on the server side. I presume with it is mergiung all the CSS & Scripts together thsi does not ply welll with knockout. Problem solved to an extent as all the headers ae back.